# Django Select and Display Model Inlines Dynamically with multiple select drop down box

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

Here is what my admin page looks like:

Here is a link of the admin page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghq5f.png

As I add more models, I will have more foreign keys related to Selector and each instance of the selector model doesn’t need all the inlines. I would like to be able to select and choose which inlines to display for simplicity of the admin page. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can simplify my page and have a dropdown multiple select box for dynamically displaying the inlines?

Here is my models.py file:

```
    from django.db import models
class Selector(models.Model):
    lst = [
        ("Model1", "Model1"),
        ("Model2", "Model2"),
        ("Model3", "Model3"),
        ("Model4", "Model4"),
    ]
    choice = models.CharField("Choices", choices=lst, max_length=40)



class Model1(models.Model):
    select = models.ForeignKey(Selector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param1 = models.IntegerField("Input 1")
    param2 = models.IntegerField("Input 2")
    param3 = models.IntegerField("Input 3")


class Model2(models.Model):
    select = models.ForeignKey(Selector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param1 = models.IntegerField("Input 1")
    param2 = models.IntegerField("Input 2")
    param3 = models.IntegerField("Input 3")


class Model3(models.Model):
    select = models.ForeignKey(Selector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param1 = models.IntegerField("Input 1")
    param2 = models.IntegerField("Input 2")
    param3 = models.IntegerField("Input 3")


class Model4(models.Model):
    select = models.ForeignKey(Selector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    param1 = models.IntegerField("Input 1")
    param2 = models.IntegerField("Input 2")
    param3 = models.IntegerField("Input 3")
```

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Model1, Model2, Model3, Model4, Selector


class Model1Admin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model1
    extra = 1


class Model2Admin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model2
    extra = 1


class Model3Admin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model3
    extra = 1


class Model4Admin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model4
    extra = 1


class SelectorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Selector
    inlines = [Model1Admin, Model2Admin, Model3Admin, Model4Admin]


admin.site.register(Selector, SelectorAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

try out

```
class Model1Admin(admin.StackedInline):
model = Model1
extra = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_